"Protobuf C++ gencode is built with an incompatible version of"
I'm encountering an error when trying to build my C++ project. The error message reads: "Protobuf C++ gencode is built with an incompatible version of."
Both gRPC and Protobuf are on the latest version:
brew info grpc
==> grpc: stable 1.62.2 (bottled), HEAD
brew info protobuf
==> protobuf: stable 26.1 (bottled)

Protobuf files are built using cmake:
set(_GRPC_GRPCPP gRPC::grpc++)
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
  find_program(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE grpc_cpp_plugin)
else()
  set(_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE $<TARGET_FILE:gRPC::grpc_cpp_plugin>)
endif()

# Gets the protos file path
get_filename_component(PROTO_FILE "./proto/proto.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(PROTO_FILE_PATH "${PROTO_FILE}" PATH)

# Sets the location for generated files
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/)
set(PROTO_SOURCES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/proto.pb.cc")
set(PROTO_HEADERS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/proto.pb.h")
set(GRPC_SOURCES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/proto.grpc.pb.cc")
set(GRPC_HEADERS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/proto.grpc.pb.h")

set_property(SOURCE ${GRPC_SOURCES} ${PROTO_SOURCES} ${GRPC_HEADERS} ${PROTO_HEADERS} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ON)

# Generate *.pb.* and *.qrpc.* files from .proto file
add_custom_command (
  OUTPUT "${PROTO_SOURCES}" "${PROTO_HEADERS}" "${GRPC_SOURCES}" "${GRPC_HEADERS}"
  COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
  ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/"
       --cpp_out "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated/"
       -I "${PROTO_FILE_PATH}"
       --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
       "${PROTO_FILE}"
  DEPENDS "${PROTO_FILE}"
)

I reinstalled both packages but nothing seems to work. I tried uninstalling abseil too, but nope.
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force grpc opencv protobuf abseil
brew cleanup
brew autoremove
brew install grpc opencv

Other errors (i don't know if they help):


Have you checked protoc version?

@jpa yes, it's the same as what brew says, libprotoc 26.1

What is the version in generated .pb.h files? It should have a version number near the beginning.

// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
// source: proto.proto
// Protobuf C++ Version: 5.26.1

Ok, so that matches. Then it is probably finding old version of #include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h" from somewhere.

any ideea on how i can/delete that?

First check where it is including that file from (compilers have a command line flag to show list of included files, GCC uses -H)

This error is emitted from the #ifdef near the beginning of the generated .pb.h file:
// Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
...
// Protobuf C++ Version: 5.28.0-dev
...
#include "google/protobuf/runtime_version.h"
#if PROTOBUF_VERSION != 5026000
#error "Protobuf C++ gencode is built with an incompatible version of"
#error "Protobuf C++ headers/runtime. See"
#error "https://protobuf.dev/support/cross-version-runtime-guarantee/#cpp"
#endif

The PROTOBUF_VERSION define comes from runtime_version.h, while the 5026000 value it is compared against is written by protoc when it generates the file.
To debug the issue, first verify that the generated .pb.h file contains the version number you expect. If it does not, your build process is using a different version of protoc. Search your path for other installed versions using whereis protoc.
If the generated .pb.h version is correct, then the problem is in the included runtime_version.h. Instruct the compiler to show full path of the included files. For GCC and clang this can be done using the -H command line switch. Then when you discover the outdated installation, either uninstall it or adjust your include path to ignore it.

Version Contained in the .pb.h is 5.26.1 which is the one I have installed (26.1)
whereis protoc outputs only protoc: /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc , if I uninstalled it, it outputs nothing.
Then I did
g++ -o main main.cc -H -I$(brew --prefix)/include -L$(brew --prefix)/lib -lgrpc -lprotobuf in order to build main including the .pb.h and see what is included, but there is no runtime_versions.h
all protos are from the same dir, for example:
/opt/homebrew/include/google/protobuf/port_def.inc

maybe a complete uninstall of Homebrew and all its packages will reset this problem?

Complete reinstall didn't fix the issue.

@Lys4nder For some versions it could be port_def.inc also. But reading the .pb.h file should be pretty clear which header it is getting the version from, and then you can read that file to see what the version is.

problem was cmake was finding grpc 1.48 and protobuf 26.1.
I figured that out in CmakeCache.txt, where protobuf was linked from anaconda3 which was wrong. I deleted it and now it works. Thanks @jpa for guiding me!
